# Use \label and cross-references in xymatrix

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, xy-pic

Whenever I am trying to use `\caption`, `\label` and cross-references in `xymatrix`, it is not working. An MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix{ A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
C\ar[r] & D
\caption{Rectangular diagram}
\label{Fig1}
}
$$
The above figure \ref{Fig1} is a commutative diagram.
\end{document}
```

Anyone can tell me how do I fix this problem ?

Comment: "It is not working" is not descriptive enough. Why not post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate what the problem is?

Comment: Without a minimum working example, it is hard to see what you are trying.  But when in doubt, I always try to `\protect` things like `\caption` and `\label` if they don't seem to work in a situation.

Comment: Ok, I shall update my post soon with MWE.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: You need to use a float environment like `figure` or `table` to use the `\caption` macro. If you don't want a float, take a look at the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package. Besides that, the package is simply called `xy`: `\usepackage[all]{xy}` works.

Comment: You need to wrap your diagram, label and caption in `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions. Also, don't use `$$` for display math, use `\[ ... \]` (see [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?lq=1))

Comment: There is no package called `xymatrix`

Comment: The required package for 'xymatrix' is **'xypic'**

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar `xymatrix` is environment defined in [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) package which is loaded by `\usepackage[all]{xy}` in preamble

Comment: Friendly advice my dear: forum can better serve you when one learns from [past](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:26385+[xy-pic]) and kindly accept answer with `green tick` to encourage/thank people. All the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\caption` macro only works in float environments like `table` or `figure` (unless you want a non-floating description for a figure, then you can use the `\captionof` macro provided by the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package or the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes.

The `\xymatrix` is not horizontally centered by default, you can use either LaTeX’s `\[ … \]` macros (which adds vertical space that is removed with `\tightdisplaymath`) or—not recommended—a manual centering with the `\centerline` macro or a pair of `\hspace{\fill}`.

*Do not use `[h]` or `[h!]` in your document. It is only used here to show the floats on one page. If you want fixed positions in your running text use `\captionof` or simply a numbered math environment.*

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tightdisplaymath}{\abovedisplayskip\z@\belowdisplayskip\z@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\hrulefill

\begin{figure}[h] 
 \[ \xymatrix{
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C \ar[r]       & D
 } \]
\caption{Rectangular diagram}\label{Fig1a}
\end{figure}

\hrulefill

\begin{figure}[h] \tightdisplaymath
 \[ \xymatrix{
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C \ar[r]       & D
 } \]
\caption{Rectangular diagram}\label{Fig1b}
\end{figure}

\hrulefill

\begin{figure}[h] \centerline{%
 \xymatrix{
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C \ar[r]       & D
 }}
\caption{Rectangular diagram}\label{Fig2}
\end{figure}

\hrulefill

\begin{figure}[h!]
 \hspace{\fill}%
 \xymatrix{
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
  C \ar[r]       & D
 }%
 \hspace{\fill}
 \caption{Rectangular diagram}\label{Fig3}
\end{figure}

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

Figure \ref{Fig1a} and \ref{Fig1b} are commutative diagrams.

Figure \ref{Fig2} is the same commutative diagram.

Figure \ref{Fig3} is also the same commutative diagram.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Caption cannot be used that way. And please don't use `$$...$$` in a LaTeX document. Basically you are trying to add a caption inside the cell containing `D`. Normally one would not make a commutative diagram into a figure, but leave it as a mathematical construction can giving it an equation number, say using

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
\xymatrix{ A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
C\ar[r] & D }
\end{aligned}
\label{Fig1}
\end{gather}
The above  \eqref{Fig1} is a commutative diagram.
\end{document}
```

the use of `aligned` is to ensure the eqn number is vertically centered on the diagram

Comment: I'd use `equation` for the outer environment and `gathered` for the inner one.

Comment: True, but I don't think it would have made much of a difference in this case.